# Ruby Mechanize - how to set wait till a web page is fully loaded

Tags: ruby

This is my first time using ruby Mechanize to perform web crawling. It works fine till one of the websites it never returns an expected URL link because the web page isn't fully loaded but Machanize alredy search the web page.
Below is my code

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(website_url)
page.links.each do |link|
    tmp_href_str = "#{link.href}".to_s   
    job_title =    "#{link.text.strip}".to_s
    job_title = job_title.gsub(/\r\n?/, ' ')
    job_title_length = "#{link.text.strip}".to_s.length
end
```

Comment: or start searching the html page till the <div class="result"> appear. Anyone please give me some advice.

Comment: I am not familiar with mechanize, But can't you use `watir` to perform the same task? Why do you prefer mechanize? any reason?